# Change selection color in tableview and textfield javafx

Tags: java, css, javafx, tableview, textfield

Tell me, how do I change the marked color of the highlight in css in the pictures (javaFX)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] read [this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)

Comment: This question did not deserve to be down voted and accumulate so many close votes.  Sometimes a picture is worth a thousand words or a thousand lines of code.  An mcve was not necessary.  In this case, the issue was clear from the posted image and one line CSS fix was clear to anybody who understands JavaFX CSS processing.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution!

```
  -fx-accent: #color;
```